How to change grub or boot settings in ubuntu 24.10
i want to change the time to enter a so either ubuntu or windows and also save the session from the previous  last enter so.
i was doing that on ubuntu 24.04 but then i reinstalled and today i upgraded to ubuntu 24.10
i was told on a procedure on  the answer to my question my previous question
the answer checked, and acepted , on the 3rd point, because i dont want now to look like manjaro, so i skip the first 2 steps if i do
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
a blank page appears and i can not change the values or parameters of the file.
so i am guessing the boot or grub file have changed name and i dont know the name, or i have to do something different
so if someone help me with this, change the time that the grub automatically enter a so, either ubuntu or windows and log to the last so entered
And i mean an answer how to do in a simple way, like the previous answer to my question
And i am a very basic normal linux user,my knowladge is very limted

You should have the file /etc/default/grub and it shouldn't be empty. However, you can copy a fresh,virgin instance of that file from /usr/share/grub/default/grub. The command to do that is sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/grub. Then try again to edit.

it worked at least the file was not empty anymore

i realized i made a mistake i wrote sudo nano /etc/default/grub~instead of
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

i did a mistake somehow and now i cant see the boot or grub menu and the system go straigth to ubuntu 24.10 and i cant select the operating system. can you help me?

First procede withe step 3 and 4 from the answer to your previous question.
